How to constrain a generic type with an alias derived from a union type in Python
quick summary:
I want the function combine to take two arguments with the same type. It is the generic type T.
And T is one element certain union type     possibleTypeForCombine = int | str. I want to constraint by  possibleTypeForCombine not the type it include because the definition of     possibleTypeForCombine can change. By doing this way mypy will detect a problem if I don t adapt the pattern matching in the function combine

I'm trying to improve a function that combines two values of the same type, currently supporting int and str. Here's my current implementation:
def combine[T: (int, str)](a: T, b: T) -> T:
    match a:
        case int():
            return a + b
        case str():
            return a + " " + b

This passes mypy type checking. However, I want to make it more extensible for future additions of other types. I'd like to use a type alias possibleTypeForCombine to represent the allowed types. I've tried defining it as:
possibleTypeForCombine = int | str
# or
from typing import Union
possibleTypeForCombine = Union[int, str]

My goal is to be able to easily add new types to possibleTypeForCombine in the future, and  mypy informs me where I need to add new cases in functions using this type.
I attempted to use this type alias in a new version of the function:
def combine2[T: possibleTypeForCombine](a: T, b: T) -> T:
    match a:
        case int():
            c = a + b
            return c
        case str():
            c = a +" " + b
            return c

However, this results in the following mypy errors:

error: Missing return statement  [return] error: Unsupported operand
types for + ("str" and "T")  [operator] error: Incompatible return
value type (got "str", expected "T")  [return-value]

Of course I expected that. THe syntax to constrain a generic type is T: (possible type 1, possible type 2).
I would like to know if this is nevertheless possible to make something similar

by using possibleTypeForCombine you are trying to expand the input type of function,what are you thinking then, how about case something(): you are planning to type that manually?

What is wrong with your current implementation? When I try adding a new type I get error: Missing return statement  [return]. It is perhaps vague, but it identifies that there is a missing return statement for the new type.

As an aside, the match statement in the example is redundant. The body of the function can be implemented as return a + b and it will still pass type checking. It will still require that a, b and the return value to have the same type. If one of the constrained types was bool, then you'd need the match statement.

This question is lacking some details necessary for a definitive answer. "However, I want to make it more extensible for future additions of other types.": As I'm sure you already know, you can do this simply by adding other types to the list/tuple of contraints (e.g., def combine2[T: (int, str, bytes)](...)). If you insist on using a type alias, please show us why such an alias is necessary. This can be done by including a more realistic simplification of your actual code.

Your code is already as extensible as it needs to be. You can simply add a new type to the constraint tuple (int, str), and the function will now be checked for that type as well. What it seems you are missing, is the ability for the type checker to highlight when you have missed adding code to handle the new type. As it stands, the type checker will already highlight that you have not covered all your bases. It will see that the new type causes your function to reach the end of its execution block without hitting a return statement. This is reported as the error:
mytypes.py:8 error: Missing return statement  [return]

The problem comes if your code has a default branch that raises an exception. This will mask the programming error. The following snippet will pass type checking, despite never being able to return a value for the new type that T may take (set).
def combine[T: (int, str, set)](x: T, y: T) -> T:
    match x:
        case int():
            return x + y
        case str():
            return x + y
        case _:
            raise RuntimeError(f'Unreachable code got: {type(x)}')

Instead of raising a runtime error, what you want to do is use assert_never(). This function helps the type checker know that a piece of code should never be executed. It also helps reveal which type means that assert_never() will be called with. Finally, the function raises an assertion error if it is ever actually called, and shows the type of the argument it was called with.
Continuing on from the above example, set is kept as one of the possible types T can take, and then we get the default branch of the match statement to call assert_never().
from typing import assert_never

def combine[T: (int, str, set)](x: T, y: T) -> T:
    match x:
        case int():
            return x + y
        case str():
            return x + y
        # case set():
        #    return x | y
        case _ as unreachable:
            assert_never(unreachable)

As it stands, mypy will report the that assert_never(unreachable) is called with the type set[Any], with the following message:
mytypes.py:12: error: Argument 1 to "assert_never" has incompatible type "set[Any]"; expected "Never"  [arg-type]

If the commented code is uncommented, then the function copes will all types again and passes type checking.

thanks but this is not really what I want. I want to tell. The function take two argument with the same time T and T is une possibility of a certain union type

I not sure I understand your comment. Perhaps you should provide example calls that you want to allow and example calls that you want to disallow. This answer accepts combine(int, int) and combine(str, str), but rejects combine(int, str).

I looked at your question again and I think you do want to accept combine(int, str).  I think i was confused as your sample code would error out in such a scenario. I think you need to say what the return type should be in such a scenario. Should the return type be int, or str or int | str? That is, should the return type be the type of the first arg, or the second or a union of the first arg type and second arg type? All are possible, I just don't know what you want.

Just for comparison to Dunes's answer, you can use an overload as well.
from typing import overload

@overload
def combine(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    ...

@overload
def combine(a: str, b: str) -> str:
    ...

def combine(a, b):
    match (a, b):
        case (int(), int()):
            ...
        case (str(), str()):
            ...
        case _:
            raise ValueError("Both arguments must be ints, or both must be strs")

The overload defines something like Callable[[int, int], int] | Callable[[str, str], str]: note the union involves the function type itself, not the argument types or the return type.

thanks but my example is simplified. I really need to a match statement because I am doing different things if this is a string or an int. I will change it in the description

You can still use the match statement in the actual definition; the two decorated functions are only used by the type checker.

To be clear, you don't want possibleTypeForCombine to be a Union. A TypeVar constrained to multiple values is distinct from a union over those values. Here is an option that works but doesn't use the modern 3.12 syntax:
from typing import TypeAlias, TypeVar

possibleTypeForCombine = TypeVar('possibleTypeForCombine', int, str)

def combine(a: possibleTypeForCombine, b: possibleTypeForCombine) -> possibleTypeForCombine:
    match a:
        case int():
            c = a + b
            return c
        case str():
            c = a + " " + b
            return c
        case _:
            raise TypeError

demo
To change the supported types, simply add them to the possibleTypeForCombine variable.
According to PEP-695 (which specifies the new 3.12 typing syntax), the constrained type variable specification must be made using "a literal tuple expression that contains two or more types." It cannot be made using a variable/alias in this situation. Here is the example from the PEP showing it isn't supported:
t1 = (bytes, str)
class ClassE[T: t1]: ...  # Type checker error: literal tuple expression required


This is the correct answer I believe.  This answer helps explain why OP doesn't want a union as well. Put really simply, OP expects that if a is a str, then so is b. This actually isn't satisfied by a union - a being a str and b being an int would be valid. Hence, TypeVar is needed.

You should use TypeVar with constraints instead of inline Generics
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", int, str)


def combine2(a: T, b: T) -> T:
    match a:
        case int():
            c = a + b
            return c
        case str():
            c = a + b
            return c

gist

Have you checked to see if this works as intended?

@InSync omitting the problem with missing default return (I let the OP to deal with that), it does pass mypy checks

Yet combine2(1, 2) and combine2('1', '2') both fail.

@sudden_appearance I don t think it is what i need. it doesn't work with combine (1,2) and combine("ab","b") and it mypy isn t able to understand that there are 2 cases only

@InSync sorry, I updated the answer with what seems to be desired behaviour.

@sudden_appearance you use the old generic syntax. And without the using the alias type, I already can do it (see the the first lines of code I submitted) But thanks for your effort
